# how to replace the default splash screen

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen

I have Cordova app  that I create with the command --> cordova create MyProject --template cordova-template-mfp.

Where do I put my own icon and splash screen?. I tried to replace the splash screen in  the res folder but I still see the IBM screen.

I have the cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "" installed and this is a snippet of my folder structure

MyProject

-- res

-- hooks

-- platform

---- android

---- iOS

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/cordova-apps/adding-images-and-icons/

> If you used the MobileFirst template when you created your app, you must update the splash images that Cordova uses. Change the source paths and file names (`src`) to the path of the files that you want to display. Add lines similar to the following example between the `<platform name="android">` and `</platform>` tags in the **config.xml** file:

```
<splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />  
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />  
<splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />  
<splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />  
<splash density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />  
<splash density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />  
<splash density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />  
<splash density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

-remove/delete your resources folder

```
cordova resources
```

then copy/paste your **.png** image inside the new resource folder created
then do

```
cordova resources
cordova build <platform>
```

And as per requirement by cordova/ionic splash screen should be 1200x1200px

Comment: Please note that `resources/` can contain files that `cordova resources` does not generate, so you might lose them if you choose to try this method